# appending lightbox to existing gallery jquery

Tags: jquery, html

I am trying to attach lightbox to gallery on site. Gallery has such structure, where class="flex-active-slide" is changing depend which photo is currently main.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ej1gm.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MXxAW.png)

By jquery I inserted tag a which surround tag img and adding attribute rel="lightbox" to tag a allowed to display lightbox effect.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jzLgW.png)

This script works for six img. How to generalise solution for unknown in advance amount of photos/ tags img?
I'm happy that script works, but I am confused why it's generating one additional tag a, to which not adding href and rel. Maybe you know where it comes from? [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nlTCq.png)

```
var znacznik1 = $('.slides');
znacznik1.children().attr('class', 'myLi')

var znacznik2 = $(".myLi");
znacznik2.children().attr('class', 'image');
var i = 0;
$('.image').each(function(){
if(i<6){
i++;
}
else{
i=1;
}

$(this).attr('id','myImg' + i);

var img = document.getElementById("myImg" + 
i);
var tohref = img.getAttribute("src");

$('#myImg' + i).wrap('<a id="lightboxxx' + i 
+ '"></a>');
var lightbox = $('#lightboxxx' + i); 
lightbox.attr('href', tohref.toString());
lightbox.attr('rel', 'lightbox');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

for the first question: I added

```
var count = ($(".slides").children().length)/2;
```

and changed 6 to count